# How to get a list of S3ObjectSummaries from S3 by a list of file names?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket with A LOT of files, so much so that getting all of them then iterating over etc, is just not performant enough. I'd like to be able to grab 500 or so at a time from the bucket by S3 file-names. But I'm not sure how to do that without making individual requests to S3, can I batch this somehow?

Right now my object request looks like:

```java
ListObjectsRequest objectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest()
        .withBucketName(getBucketName())
        .withPrefix(getPrefix());
```

Then I obviously have to iterate over them, and look for the 500 or so that I want (this is really slow because the bucket is massive).

I would like to be able to do something like:

```java
ListObjectsRequest objectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest()
        .withBucketName(getBucketName())
        .withPrefix(getPrefix())
        .withFileNames(getFileNames());
```

Which would return the 500 or so files I'm looking for.

How can I do this? Is it possible?

Comment: No, you can't do that but you can use a combination of Prefix and [MaxKeys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ListObjectsRequest.html#withMaxKeys-java.lang.Integer-). Alternatively, if the bucket is fairly static, a daily S3 inventory list might suffice.

Comment: @jarmod Hmm I don't think that will do what I need. Mainly because I'll need all of files I'm looking for at once. If I query by `MaxKeys` I think I'll just get the first bunch over and over.

Comment: Right, it won't do that because it can't do that. Alternatively, issue up to 500 HeadObject requests to see if the desired object(s) exist.

Comment: Why are you wanting to 'list' objects given that you already know the keys of the objects? What are you _actually_ wanting to achieve out of this?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein The files are the result of AWS DataSync and my database knows nothing of their size unfortunately I need to get their size into the database that keeps track of them.

Comment: Have you considered creating an AWS Lambda function that is triggered when objects are created in the bucket? The Lambda function could retrieve the size of the object and update your database. This would happen as soon as the objects appear, rather than having to scan for them later.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein That was my initial plan but unfortunately the DataSync was run before I had a chance to implement it. It was not my choice.

Comment: Can you implement the Lambda functionality for 'future' objects, and then do something one-off for the 'existing' objects? If so, performance won't matter for the existing objects.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein unfortunately everything has already been moved, future sync's wont happen. This was for a one-time data migration from some non-S3 data store, I think we really screwed up by missing out on implementing this lambda.

Comment: If this is a one-off activity, you can use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily or weekly CSV file listing all objects. You could then populate your database from this list.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Brilliant! I will take that as an answer if you'd be so kind as to provide it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a one-off activity, you can use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily or weekly CSV file listing all objects.

You could then populate your database from this list.

The list includes the object name and the size of the object, which is what you are seeking.

Comment: @Jarmod mentioned it too!